# Error Occur When Grails project Import

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite, grails-2.2

Good day all members

I see error When I import Grails project to GGTS.
Error is below.

> Import Grails project  has encountered a problem.Invalid project
>   description. Project is overlaps the location of another project.

If anyone know help me please.

Comment: The project location is may be in use by JVM OR TOMCAT OR ANYOTHER restart

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is a conflict between the project your are importing and something in your workspace that has the same name. I beleave this can happen in one of two different ways

1) You have a project in your Eclipse workspace already that has the same name

2) You do not have a project in your workspace with the same name, but you do have a folder or file on your hard-drive stored in the workspace directory that has the same name as your project.

My guess is that most likely you are in the second case, which would be less obvious to see.

So check your workspace folder on disk for a conflicting file/folder and either delete, rename or move it. Then try importing again.